# Why do I have to use static everywhere? And how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, class, static, instance

I am writing a small program in C# and at the start i noticed that Visual studio is complaining about having to use only static variables and static function calls in static functions (including the main). I have coded before, although i have to mention that i have coded before, and i cant remember being forced to use static everywhere. Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    string word = "asd";
    static List<string> words = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        OpenFile();
        Debug.WriteLine(words.Count);
        anagram();

    }

    public static void OpenFile()
    {

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("wordlist.txt"))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                words.Add(line);
            }

        }

    }

    public void anagram()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(word);

    }

}
```

I am getting the error " Error  CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.anagram()' " and i just dont understand why? Also i wanted to make the words variable non-static as well but since the method is static that i am using it in it "has to be". Is there any way to avoid this? 
I think i have a good understanding of what static is but i just don't want to use it here.

Any help is appreciated an thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are going to need just to look up the C# reference guide. Unless you create an instance of a class, you can only access its static methods.

Comment: static is required only on the program entry point (conventionally the main method) everywhere else you could use an instance of the class Program and access variables and methods without the static keyword

Comment: The simplest fix is to do `new Program().DoYourStuff()` in the `Main` methods and you can use instance fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your logic into another class and create an instance of it and use its members.

```
public class MyClass
{
    string word = "asd";
    public List<string> Words = new List<string>();

    public void OpenFile()
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("wordlist.txt"))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Words.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public void anagram()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

Then your main method would be like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new MyClass();
    m.OpenFile();
    Debug.WriteLine(m.Words.Count);
    m.anagram();
}
```

You should read more about access modifiers and how static members and instance members are different.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your class like this:

```
class Program
{
    public string word = "asd";
    public List<string> words = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.OpenFile();
        Debug.WriteLine(program.words.Count);
        program.anagram();

    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("wordlist.txt"))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                this.words.Add(line);
            }

        }

    }

    public void anagram()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine(this.word);
    }

}
```

Static methods are generic to the class - if you want to use non-static, you need to instantiate an instance of it.